# Problem with php explode, trying to separate a string

Tags: php, explode

im having a problem with this string

```
string(313) "
12312312312312312
12312312312312312
12312312312312312
12312312312312312
12312312312312312
12312312312312312
12312312312312312
12312312312312312
12312312312312312
12312312312312312"
```

The result i want is = `array("12312312312312312","12312312312312312")` etc...

I want to separate the entrys to put into thearray, i tryied all this methods with php:

```
$numbers= explode("\n",$numbers); 

$numbers= explode(" ",$numbers);

$numbers= explode("<br>",$numbers);  

$numbers= str_replace("\n", " ", "<br>", $numbers)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `explode()` with  new line (`PHP_EOL`):

```
$numbers= array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL, $numbers)); // PHP_EOL used for new line

print_r($numbers);
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/0OH4N

Note:- `array_filter()` used to remove empty,null value indexes from array

Answer (score 0):

First replace any newline element with a simple space e.g. like

```
$numbers = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $numbers));
```

Than you can simply use the explode you've already tried:

```
$numbers = explode(" ",$numbers);
```

Comment: After I tidied up the question, it appears the string is NewLine seperated :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly the `s+` also can handle `\n` and `\r`. I've tested it with the tidied up code ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the string in this order.
This may help you

```
$str ="12312312312312312 12312312312312312 12312312312312312 12312312312312312 12312312312312312 12312312312312312 12312312312312312";
var_dump(explode(" ",$str));
```